# C++ multithreading: keep only one thread (other than the main thread) alive at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function that does some heavy tasks, so I would like to run it in a thread other than the main thread. The code looks like:

```
Data global_data;
void heavy_task() {
    ...//update global_data
}

void main() {
    while (True) {
        if (user_press_w) {
            std::thread t(heavy_task);
            t.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify the code so that only one thread is running at a time? For example, if the user presses w which starts a thread and then before the first thread with heavy_task finishes, she presses w again, the first thread will stop and the second one starts to run. This would also be helpful in the situation when the user keeps pressing the key, in which case only the thread triggered by the last time key detection stays alive.

----------------- Solution -------------------

I have revised my code as suggested by Adrian Colomitchi,

```
std::shared_ptr<std::thread> my_thread;
bool should_terminate = false;

Data global_data;
void heavy_task() {
    // This function actually does its work in a loop
    // so I check should_terminate at each iteration
    while (...) {
        ...
        if (should_terminate) return;
    }
}

void main() {
    while (True) {
        if (user_press_w) {
            should_terminate = true;
            if (my_thread!= nullptr && my_thread->joinable()) 
                my_thread->join();
            my_thread= std::make_shared<thread>(heavy_task);
            should_terminate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

--------------- The situation -------------------

I am writing an interactive ray tracing program. The world is first drawn by an OpenGL application, the user navigates through the world to choose a satisfying viewpoint and presses a key to start ray tracing. Before the ray tracing finishes, the user can change the viewpoint and presses the key to start a fresh new ray tracing. I use glfw to talk with operating system.

Comment: _"How can I modify the code so that only one thread is running at a time?"_ How does that make sense? Why using threads then at all?

Comment: Set your heavy-task Thread to IDLE priority. The CPU will put it into background when possible and if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mean run only one thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Just create one additional thread and code it to do exactly what you want to do at all times. That way, you'll never need to stop it or create another thread because that thread will already be doing what you want. When you feel you need to stop or interrupt a thread, that should immediately be a sign that you didn't code it to do what you actually wanted it to do. You should not need to "force" the code to do the right thing because it should never have been written to do the wrong thing in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do, if you press _w_ again, you want to delete the current thread and start a new one (like start again)? This makes no sense without a real application example.

Comment: @shapeare `t.detach();` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @cpatricio "This makes no sense without a real application example." Imagine one. Say... the algorithmic/fractal generation of a landscape - if you like what you see on screen at lower levels of generation you let it continue. If you don't like it, you press they magic key which tells the program "try something else" (or "stop this stream, I've seen enough. Go to the next one").

Comment: @shapeare `void main()` isn't valid c++ BTW.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi  Yes. I am actually writing an interactive ray tracing program. The world is first drawn by an OpenGL application, the user navigates through the world to choose a satisfying viewpoint and presses a key to start ray tracing. Before the ray tracing finishes, the user can change the viewpoint and presses the key to start a fresh new ray tracing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ    Thanks for pointing out. I will pay attention next time.

Comment: @shapeare Note that `should_terminate` is prone to race conditions. At least that should be a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: @shapeare [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414025/c-multithreading-keep-only-one-thread-other-thatn-the-main-thread-alive-at?noredirect=1#comment68078592_40414025) is very important information that needs to go into your question. Otherwise it's completely unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi do you have signals for keypress? If you have you can terminate the thread and create a new one.

Comment: @cpatricio "do you have signals for keypress?" I don't know, from `if (user_press_w) ` I can't infer it. "If you have you can terminate the thread and create a new one" Not a nice thing to do in all circumstances - sometimes (most of the times?) it's necessary to let the things in a consistent state when interrupted (e.g. let your source code in a compilable state when the project is shelved)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi it depends on operating system, for example for windows you can use [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @cpatricio  I suspect the app is coded with a Windowing framework which may not even be Windows API  - perhaps Qt or the like (to keep the things as portable as possible). The Window/Frame/whatevs and the component that has the focus are too important aspects to ignore and go with system-wide keyboard intercepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `heavy_task` interruptible: while doing the things, periodically check a flag which should tell it if it is to continue or drop everything and exit prematurely.

With this in place, when you receive another command for a heavy task, you raise first the "interrupt" flag, **join** the worker thread to make sure it "died" (so, no `thread.detach()` before) and then launch the new `heavy_task`.

Something on the lines of:

```
Data global_data;

void heavy_task(bool& shouldStop) {
    while(! ready && ! shouldStop) {
      // update **some** global data, in as small slices as you can afford
    }
}

void main() {
    bool interruptWThread=false;

    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> thread;

    while (True) {
        if (user_press_w) {
            if(thread) {
              interruptWThread=true;
              thread->join(); // wait here until thread exit is confirmed
              interruptWThread=false;
            }
            thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(
              [& interruptWThread]->heavy_task(interruptWThread)
            );
            // nope!! Never detach a thread you may still need later
            // t.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to set `interruptWThread` back to `false` before launching the next thread.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeap, so it was. Thank you

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Your approach waits for the the thread to finish the job before launching it again, so it's good for tasks that are mandatory. My approach targets the tasks that can be abandoned midway. Two different solutions for two different needs.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Well, I can't read that requirement from the OP's question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "I can't read that requirement from the OP's question." granted, it's a bit ambiguous. Given the OP's latests edits and the fact the my answer was accepted, it seems OP needs to deal with interruptible tasks (e.g listening to streamed music and deciding you want to skip the current one and go to the one above. Or gaming, in which your player does a thing until told: "Go up one position and start doing the same again")